# Solve issue with nested keys in JSON

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am trying to adapt some python code from an awesome guide for dark web scanning/graph creation.

I have thousands of json files created with Onionscan, and I have this code that should wrap everything in a gephi graph. Unfortunately, this code is old, as the Json files are now formatted differently and this code does not work anymore:

code (partial):

```
import glob
import json
import networkx
import shodan

file_list = glob.glob("C:\\test\\*.json")
graph = networkx.DiGraph()

for json_file in file_list:
    with open(json_file,"rb") as fd:
        scan_result = json.load(fd)
        edges = []
        if scan_result('linkedOnions') is not None:
            edges.extend(scan_result['linkedOnions'])
```

In fact, at this point I get "KeyError", because linkedOnions is one-level nested like this:

```
"identifierReport": {
 "privateKeyDetected": false,
  "foundApacheModStatus": false,
  "serverVersion": "",
  "relatedOnionServices": null,
  "relatedOnionDomains": null,
  "linkedOnions": [many urls here]
```

could you please help me fix the code above?

I would be VERY grateful :)

Lorenzo

Comment: It looks like it should be `scan_result['identifierReport']['linkedOnions']`, but your example isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct way to read nested JSON.

```
if scan_result['identifierReport']['linkedOnions'] is not None:
            edges.extend(scan_result'identifierReport']['linkedOnions'])
```

Try this it will work for you if your JSON file is correct format

```
try:
   scan_result = json.load(fd)
   edges = []
   if scan_result('linkedOnions') is not None:
      edges.extend(scan_result['linkedOnions'])
except Exception,e:
     #print your message or log
     print e
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. However, I have some bad json files in my directory.So...is there a way to skip those files and keep creating the graph without quitting the process??

Comment: I have added exception handling in the code so that you can skip bad files.